# Cannot compile Qt with Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt, compilation

I updated Xcode to 6.0.1 and found I cannot compile the Qt project in Qt creater anymore because of this:

warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk'

error: 'TargetConditionals.h' file not found

Can anyone help me, please? How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the output of `ls /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs`. `MacOSX10.9.sdk` is likely listed, and it should be used rather than `MacOSX10.8.sdk`.

Comment: I don't have such problem, but I compiled Qt myself with homebrew after I updated Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem as yours and downloading MacOSX10.8.sdk from this location :

[GitHub - Phracker](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs)

and copying it to

**/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/S‌​DKs**

solved the problem !

cheers

Comment: You should probably provide an Apple download for the SDK, and not a GitHub download.

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to debug your code with the Xcode 6 debugger.  You should rename Xcode 6 as Xcode6.app and then reinstall Xcode 5.1.1 as Xcode.app in your Applications folder.  And then wait until Qt officially supports Xcode 6 and the 10.9.SDK.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the following with Qt5.3 to allow QtCreator to work with MacOSX10.9 and Xcode 6.0.1.
Add the following line to qt-install-dir/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/qdevice.pri:
`!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.9`

To enable iOS builds to work, add the following line to qt-install-dir/5.3/ios/mkspecs/qdevice.pri:
`!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = iphoneos8.0`

Update:
To use XCode 6.1 for iOS builds, the line should be:
`!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = iphoneos8.1`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I ran the following and it worked:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk
```

and for the simulator:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

This kind of error will appear every time you upgrade Xcode

so you can remove cache file in qt before you build or just remove when you get the error

```
rm {your target build folder}/.qmake.stash
```

or

```
rm {your project folder}/.qmake.stash
```

if you don't know where to find `.qmake.stash`, try

```
find ~ -name .qmake.stash
```

**Method 2**

Not recommend because you could get build error when you use Xcdoe APP

iphoneOS

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/
sudo ln -s iPhoneOS.sdk iPhoneOS{version}.sdk
```

iPhoneSimulator

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/
sudo ln -s iPhoneSimulator.sdk iPhoneSimulator{version}.sdk
```